# Why is ExtJS 4.2.2 gridpanel actioncolumn getTip not working?

Tags: extjs4.2

Seems simple, like actioncolumn getTip config should do what API says it does. Why not?

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    text: 'Actions',
    align: 'center',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    items: [{
        icon: './images/atlas/icons/blue/settings-close-b.png',
        iconCls: 'actionColumnOneIcon',
        getTip: function (v, metadata, rec, row, col, store) {
            return 'delete ' + rec.get('name');
        },
        handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, event, record, row) {
            this.fireEvent('aggHostGridIconClick', grid, record, 'delete');
        }
    }],
    width: 75
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to initialize the tool tip singleton class in ExtJS framework. Add the following code in the launch function of your app.js.

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

Let me know.